How to remove "Exception has occurred" [FLUTTER]
When requesting to the Internet - API
I check if there is a trailer there and if there is, it shows a button
But it shows an error, and it doesn’t always show it. It shows only on some individual films..
But every time it shows:
Exception has occurred.

RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)


I tried checking using == null but it didn't help
And this happens not only with the trailer, I tried to change it also with genres there, by the way, also through [0] (List) and the same error pops up

I think you got trailer array empty.
you can add one condition there
if( model?.movieDetails?.videos?.trailers != null )
  if( model?.movieDetails?.videos?.trailers.isNotEmpty){
     final trailer = model?.movieDetails?.videos?.trailers? [0].url;
  }
}

